# How to get hovered element while interactions are disabled for it?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-extension

I'm making an extension that is similar to the browsers inspect feature. When you're in the inpect mode, the user should not be able to interact with the page elements, but the element the cursor is hovering on should be highlighted.

I'm able to show an overlay (when inspect mode is enabled), that prevents the user from interacting with the page elements. But the issue here is I'm not able to get the dimensions of the hovered element, as the overlay is on top of all other elements. Setting pointer-events to none on the overlay works, as I'm able to get the individual elements on the page beneath the overlay, but now the issue is that the user can interact with the page elements.

I tried disabling interaction of page elements by simply looping through all DOM nodes and setting `pointer-events: none`, but when I do so I don't get the element I'm hovering on (I get the `body` instead).

So my question is, how can I get the hovered element while having interactions disabled for it?

Comment: Yea using the `pointer-events: none` disables all pointer interactions. `Event.preventDefault()` makes it so that the default behaviour of an event, e.g. a click event is not executed, this may be a possible solution to your problem.

Comment: `pointer-events: none` prevents any  events, so hovering, mouseover, mouseenter, etc. all don't work. One way around it would be, if you create a flag and allow interaction with the elements based on the flag. That way you wouldn't need to use `pointer-events: none` and could still prevent interaction.

Answer (score 0):

You could attach an event handler to the `body` to intercept and cancel all mouse / keyboard / etc events during the capturing phase, then add a `mousemove` handler to the body to do your inspection. The event handler on `body` will be dispatched with the specific `event.target`.

Note that the hover pseudoelement is still activated. I don't know of an easy way to prevent this – Firefox devtools also shows hover effects during Inspect Element sessions, but Chrome does not.

Interesting side-note: specifying `pointer-events: none` on an element *does* disable the initial hover effect, although scrolling then activates it. Adding such a rule for `body *` creates a flickering effect so I suspect this is not well-charted territory.

```js
var detailsDiv = document.getElementById("details");
var overlayDiv = document.getElementById("overlay");

function cancelEvents(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
}

document.body.addEventListener("click", cancelEvents, true);
document.body.addEventListener("mousedown", cancelEvents, true);
document.body.addEventListener("mouseup", cancelEvents, true);

document.body.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
  var target = e.target;
  var bounds = target.getBoundingClientRect();
  if (target.id) {
    detailsDiv.innerHTML = summary(target, bounds);
    showOverlay(bounds);
  } else {
    detailsDiv.innerHTML = "";
    hideOverlay();
  }
});

function summary(target, bounds) {
  return "Over: " + target.id + " [" + bounds.width + "x" + bounds.height + "]";
}

function showOverlay(bounds) {
  overlayDiv.style.display = "block";
  overlayDiv.style.left = (bounds.left + window.scrollX) + "px";
  overlayDiv.style.top = (bounds.top + window.scrollY) + "px";
  overlayDiv.style.width = bounds.width + "px";
  overlayDiv.style.height = bounds.height + "px";
}

function hideOverlay() {
  overlayDiv.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#red {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

#blue {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}

#yellow {
  width: 80px;
  height: 120px;
  background: yellow;
}

/* Possibly fly in the ointment */
#yellow:hover {
  background: orange;
}

#green {
  width: 120px;
  height: 80px;
  background: green;
}

#details {
  position: fixed;
  left: 200px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#overlay {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 999;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid cyan;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="details"></div>
<div id="overlay"></div>

<div id="red" onClick="alert('Clicked red')">
  <div id="blue"></div>
</div>
<div id="yellow"></div>
<div id="green"></div>
```